# Cambiar rama master en Git

Tags: git

Soy nuevo en esto de la programación pero tengo algo de noción, mi duda es la siguiente:

Ejecuté el comando `git init` en la carpeta de mi usuario, entonces desde la terminal cuando estoy a la altura de esa carpeta en la terminal se me muestra `~git: (master)`, en vez de haber ejecutado el comando anterior en la carpeta indicada.

Mi duda es como cambiar la ubicación de la rama maestra, para que cuando este en la carpeta indicada me indique que estoy en la rama maestra y no me la muestra en mi carpeta de usuario, o si tengo que borrar la rama, ya que en la carpeta de mi usuario tengo mas carpetas propias del sistema, como documentos, musica, etc. y no quiero combinar esa carpeta con `git`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: estas usando windows o linux

Comment: puedes explicar mejor? lo que entiendo es que dices que se te genera el archivo git dentro de los archivos del sistema y no en la carpeta que estas trabajando ?

Comment: Estoy utilizando Mac, y mi error fue ejecutar  `git init` en otra carpeta y no en la de mi proyecto, y cuando me posiciono a la altura de mi carpeta de usuario mi consoloa me muestrta la rama maestra.

Comment: para cambiar es git checkout -b la_rama_nueva, hara una copia de la rama actual(master)

Answer (score 1):

*Git* mantiene todos los archivos del repositorio en una carpeta oculta llamada **.git**. Cuando ejecutas el comando `git init` en cualquier carpeta, esa carpeta se convierte en un repositorio de *Git*, esto lo puedes comprobar ejecutándo el comando `ls -a` y comprobando que se ha creado la carpeta oculta **.git** que contiene la información del repositorio recién creado.

Lo que has hecho es crear un nuevo repositorio en tu carpeta de usuario. Si aún no has realizado *commits* en este repositorio, puedes eliminarlo borrando directamente la carpeta **.git** dentro de tu carpeta de usuario con el comando `rm -rf .git`. Luego puedes crear un nuevo repositorio en la carpeta indicada, ubicándose en ella y ejecutando de nuevo el comando `git init` para inicializar un nuevo repositorio de *Git* en esa ubicación.

Answer (score 0):

Si por error hiciste git init en una carpeta solo tienes que hacer:

```
rm -rf .git
```

eso borrara el repositorio iniciado en esa carpeta. luego haces el git init en la carpeta que quieres compartit con git

Answer (score 0):

mientras no hagas cambios o un push podes mover la carpeta `.git` a donde debería estar

ahí es donde se guardan las historias de archivos

para saber que cambios hubo :

```
$ git status
```

para ver si la carpeta `.git` existe

```
$ ls -al
```

para moverla a otra carpeta:

```
$ mkdir ./otracarpeta
$ mv .git ./otracarpeta
```

si solamente hiciste un `git init` en el lugar equivocado y nada mas, puedes borrar la carpeta `.git`

si ya hiciste cambios en la carpeta correcta y querés conservar el historial, luego de mover la carpeta `.git` tendras que hacer `git status` y ver que cambios estan y cuales no (por lo general te va a decir que se movieron los archivos de carpeta)

Answer (score 0):

Si te has equivocado en donde has agregado el repositorio `git` , que solo hayas ejecutado el :

```sh
git init
```

Nos encontramos varias opciones que son.

### Mover el fichero .git

Te crea el directorio .git , dices tu "ho por dios ahí no es".

```sh
mv -r .git ./ficheroParaGit
```

Eso moverá el repositorio git al nuevo directorio.

### Eliminar el repositoro git

```sh
rm -rf .git
```

Eso borrará todo git , te quedarás sin ramas o progresos que tuvieras y sin nada, luego cuando accedas al directorio correspondiente solo te queda por ejecutar un:

```sh
git init    Inicializa el repositorio
git status  Para saber lo que vas a meter en tu respositorio
git add .   Para añadir todo.
```

Lo recomendable será que te crees un `.ignore` y pongas las cosas que no quieres añadir.